# why the animation do not work properly in my slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a jQuery simple slider it has 15 picture each five show in a slide. I have a previous button and next button.

Each next click generate a left movement by `855px` with a slider animation.
Each previous click generate a right movement by `855px` with a slider animation.

This is my jQuery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prev_button").click(function(){
        $("ul.slider").animate({
            left: "+=855"
        }, 3000, function(){
            $("ul.slider").css('left', '0');
            li_no = 0;
            $("ul.slider").find("li").each(function(){
                li_no = li_no + 1;
            });
            slide_after_this = li_no - 6;
            $('ul.slider li:gt('+slide_after_this+')').prependTo('ul.slider'); // << line changed
        });
    });

    $(".next_button").click(function(){
        //alert($("ul.slider").css("right"));
        $("ul.slider").animate({
            right: "+=855"
        }, 3000, function(){
        //alert($("ul.slider").css("right"));
            $("ul.slider").css('right', '0');
            $('ul.slider li:not(:nth-child(n+6))').appendTo('ul.slider');
        });
    });
});
```

Now I have two problems :

First one is with the previous button (left arrow) When I click it the animation shows and the elements changed but they do not wrapped with each other (I mean does not show the last elements immidiatly before the first element). I can not find the reason of this.

Second problem is with both right and left arrows it is like following :

If I click just the right arrow the slider working fine it animates and change the elements but If I click the both button in order (I mean right then left or left then right ) the elements change but the animation does not show. but I check if the routine go inside the animate function by some alerts and it is going inside but does not animate on the screen .

This is a link that may help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/mpx83tpv/18/

Answer (score 0):

you are really close try `overflow:hidden` for `.slider_container`

```
div.slider_container
{
    height:380px;
    width:855px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

edit js:

also use below code as you are using both right and left in the end the slider has both of them one of them is always zero.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".prev_button").click(function(){
        $("ul.slider").animate({
            left: "+=855"
        }, 3000);
    });

    $(".next_button").click(function(){
        //alert($("ul.slider").css("right"));
        $("ul.slider").animate({
            left: "-=855"
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

if you want a infinite scrolling you need to use right and left in this case replace your `$("ul.slider").css('right', '0');` line to `$("ul.slider").css('right', '');` do same for left as well, as you need the remove them.

for adding the next visible div implement you logic before the animation as you callbacks do it after the animation.

the tricky part would be the prev button for this after calculation of the div count you also need the set new left without animation and then call left move animation.

hope these make sense.

Comment: Did you check the link that i included?? it is in both the wrapper and the container.
I check now also my local codes it is in both of them.

Comment: check the above code change. is there any specific reason you are using both right and left.

Comment: can you try to click three clicks on the right button in this link `http://jsfiddle.net/mpx83tpv/19/` and see that 1st element not showing after 10th element.